# Decrease x value on svg inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

This code should move(slowly) a svg box with `x="4"` to `x="400"`. I used a simple loop with js, and set it with jquery.

The box should start moving down as soon as the site is loaded, but it seems to be stuck in one place.

```js
 

$(function() {
    var i;
    var down = setInterval(function() {
        move_down()
    }, 250);

    function move_down() {
        for (i = 4, i < 400, i++) {
            $("#block_green").attr({
                y: i
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```css
    body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

#block_green {
    fill: black;
    stroke: #00ff00;
    stroke-width: .5px;
}
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <svg>
        <rect x="4" y="4" width="80" height="60" id="block_green" />
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: for a starter have you checked errors in console? because you have some.

Comment: The parts of a `for` loop need to be separated by semicolons, not commas: `for (i = 4; i < 400; i++)`.  That's the syntax error, the logic error is explained in @JoshuaFerge's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change how your i is incremented (don't need the for loop because set interval is doing the looping here.) Additionally, you had commas in your for loop statement, which just caused none of your code to run (JS uses semicolons).

```js
$(function() {
  var i = 4;
  var down = setInterval(move_down, 250);

  function move_down() {
    $("#block_green").attr({
      y: i
    });
    i++
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
svg {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#block_green {
  fill: black;
  stroke: #00ff00;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg>
    <rect x="4" y="4" width="80" height="60" id="block_green" />
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `function() { move_down() }` is meaningless, same as just `move_down`

Comment: @Andrey Thanks, I was following the w3schools format